# Deleting a letter in an array of strings

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I have an array of strings

```
array = ["Hello", "This", "is", "Great"]
```

How could I remove a specific letter of a specific string in the above array?

ie. Lets say I wanted to remove the letter s in the string "is"

I know that array[2][1] is used to select the letter "s"; using that I thought maybe `.delete_at(2)(1)` could be used in a similar way, but no.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: it's not a multi-dimensional array (as one of your tags suggested). It's an array of strings. `arrays[2]` gives you the string you need. Scan through [available string methods](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html) and see if you can ask the string to change itself in the way you need. (there are several methods there, that'll help you achieve this)

Comment: In future, I suggest you wait at lease a couple of hours before selecting an answer. There's no rush.

Comment: Dont worry i didnt need your advice, but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use slice:

```
mystring = "bla"
mystring.slice!(1)
```

mystring will now return 'ba'. Using this in your example:

```
array[2].slice!(1)
```

array now returns

```
["Hello", "This", "i", "Great"]
```

Comment: slice is too specific and generalized for example case.

Comment: @kiddorails what do you mean?

Comment: @Stefan my bad. just re-read the question in detail. I thought headchefdaniel was looking to delete a character (say 's') in some array position.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that `array[2][1]` is used to select the letter `"s"`

Indeed, but `[2][1]` are *two* distinct method calls: `array[2]` invokes [`Array#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) which returns the element at the given index:

```
array[2] #=> "is"
```

`[1]` is called on that return value, i.e. `"is"`:

```
array[2][1] #=> "s"
    "is"[1] #=> "s"
```

or using a temporary variable to illustrate it:

```
string = array[2] #=> "is"
string[1]         #=> s
```

and since the return value is a string, `[1]` invokes [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).

> I thought maybe `.delete_at(2)(1)` could be used in a similar way, but no.

Array doesn't (and shouldn't) know anything about its elements. Therefore you can't ask the array to delete a portion of a string it contains. You have to ask the string to do so.

[`String#slice!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-slice-21) can be used to delete a character at a given index:

```
string = "is"

string           #=> "is"
string.slice!(1) #=> "s"
string           #=> "i"
```

Applied to your array:

```
array = ["Hello", "This", "is", "Great"]

array[2]           #=> "is"
array[2].slice!(1) #=> "s"
array[2]           #=> "i"

array #=> ["Hello", "This", "i", "Great"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use String's `delete!` method

In your case when applied to the array it would return:

```
array = ["Hello", "This", "is", "Great"]

array[2] #=> "is"

array[2].delete! "s" #=> "i"

array #=> ["Hello", "This", "i", "Great"]
```

Note that `delete!` performs a delete operation in place, returning *str*, or *nil* if *str* was not modified.